# Memory size exhausted on composer autoload_real.php

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm running on a fresh installation of PHP 5.6 in Mac OSX (via Homebrew) with mcrypt and xdebug extensions. I'm trying to run my laravel website which was working just fine before I reinstalled my computer. I've successfully installed composer and it's dependencies but when I try to run the PHP built-in server I get the next error:

```
[Sun Nov 16 10:37:35 2014] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12288 bytes) in /Users/jhon/Projects/example/api-v1/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 31
[Sun Nov 16 10:37:35 2014] PHP Stack trace:
[Sun Nov 16 10:37:35 2014] PHP   1. {main}() /Users/jhon/Projects/example/api-v1/server.php:0
[Sun Nov 16 10:37:35 2014] PHP   2. require_once() /Users/jhon/Projects/example/api-v1/server.php:19
[Sun Nov 16 10:37:35 2014] PHP   3. require() /Users/jhon/Projects/example/api-v1/public/index.php:21
[Sun Nov 16 10:37:35 2014] PHP   4. require() /Users/jhon/Projects/example/api-v1/bootstrap/autoload.php:17
```

I don't even know where to start debug because it's not even hitting my app. Memory limit is 128MB in php.ini.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are normally two `php.ini` files: one for your PHP installation that is used for the command line and one for your web server. The one you're looking at is probably for the web server. Run `php -i` from the command line to see what your memory limit is (I'm guessing it's 262144). Then find the location of your `php.ini` for your php installation (should be the same place php is installed) and change the memory limit there.